# DevExpress MVC Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

Good day guys
I'm trying to add a extra column on the grid view with this code. But when i run it. I cant click the button on the grid view. Got any idea what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

```
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "Unbound";
            column.Caption = "Action";
            column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Object
            column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
            column.ReadOnly = false;
            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent((c) =>
            {

                Html.DevExpress().Button(b =>
                {
                    b.Name = "btnVE" + c.KeyValue;
                    b.Text = "V/E";
                    b.ClientSideEvents.Click =
                    "function(s, e) { document.location='" + DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "ViewPrincipal", Action = "EditRecord" })
                    + "?key=' + s.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex); }";

                }).GetHtml();
            });
        });

        settings.Columns.Add("Id");
        settings.Columns.Add("Code");
        settings.Columns.Add("CompanyId");
        settings.Columns.Add("Description");
        settings.Columns.Add("ContactPerson");
        settings.Columns.Add("TelNo");
        settings.Columns.Add("Notes");
```

Update: 
i found the error on web via web developer tools but i dont know how to fix it
[Error button hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YBAb.png)

Comment: Are you getting error in browser console? I suspected you're using wrong sender in `s.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex)`, the sender is button object, not `MVCxGridView`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto... hmm.. i cant even fire the code. The grid view doesnt allow me to click on the added button. I cant figure out what code that will allow me to click on the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is originated from `s` which assigned to button sender on this block instead of `GridView` row:

```
Html.DevExpress().Button(b =>
{
    b.Name = "btnVE" + c.KeyValue;
    b.Text = "V/E";
    b.ClientSideEvents.Click =
    "function(s, e) { document.location='" + DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "ViewPrincipal", Action = "EditRecord" })
    + "?key=' + s.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex); }"; // ==> 's' refers to button object as sender
}).GetHtml();
```

What you should use is `GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer` object to get `KeyValue` property for corresponding row, which returns integer value from `GridViewBaseRowTemplateContainer`:

```
column.SetDataItemTemplateContent((c) =>
{
    Html.DevExpress().Button(b =>
    {
        b.Name = "btnVE" + c.KeyValue;
        b.Text = "V/E";
        b.UseSubmitBehavior = false; // prevent default submit action
        b.EnableClientSideAPI = true; // add this line if not sure
        b.ClientSideEvents.Click =
        "function(s, e) { window.location = '" + DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "ViewPrincipal", Action = "EditRecord" })
        + "?key=" + c.KeyValue.ToString() + "'; }";

    }).GetHtml();
});
```

Or using `string.Format()` which easier to read:

```
b.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ window.location = '{0}?key={1}'; }}", 
                           DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "ViewPrincipal", Action = "EditRecord" }), 
                           c.KeyValue.ToString());
```

**Notes:**

1) If you want to get row index, use `c.VisibleIndex`.

2) For cross-browser concern, I preferred `window.location` to `document.location` as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip).

Related issue: [GridView - How to define Button inside grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q459368/gridview-how-to-define-button-inside-grid)

Comment: i got some update on my main post. Can you check it out?

Comment: The JS error provided seem to be truncated. Please provide the error as text instead of image. Also read [this reference](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q463854/javascript-runtime-error-aspxaddhoveritems-is-undefined) for jQuery bundling.

Comment: Found the answer. Your answer help me to realize some things. Thanks

Comment: this gives me an error when i use your code

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditRecord(Int32)' in 'WMS_Web.Controllers.FileMaintenance.ViewPrincipalController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: In which part of code throwing the error, can you show `EditRecord` method definition? Sounds like you have `id` parameter for `EditRecord` function but you're passing different parameter name.

Comment: the previous was int.. but now ive change it to a model.It pass thru but its null

   public  ActionResult EditRecord(PrincipalModels id)
        {
            String x = id.Id;
            
            return PartialView("~/Views/FileMaintenance/Principal/EditPrincipal.cshtml", PrincipalInfo);
        }

Comment: Sounds like you don't need to pass entire model as action parameter, just pass `Id` as integer key value for each row in the `GridView`. Then you can perform query to return entire model for displaying in partial view.

Comment: Yes i did that . But it give the null error
 public  ActionResult EditRecord(int id)
        {
            int x = id;
            
            return PartialView("~/Views/FileMaintenance/Principal/EditPrincipal.cshtml", PrincipalInfo);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Apparently this should be place on the front of the view before the creation of the grid view. But i was thinking this should be a JScript. It should run asynchronous. Ohh well as long as it works. Thanks for the help @tetsuya

```
 @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors, ExtensionType = ExtensionType.Button },
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView }

    )
    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(
        new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
        new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors, ExtensionType = ExtensionType.Button },
        new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView }
    )
```