# How to go to a link using the href value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Due to design considerations I cannot put an Anchor tag around elements but I can add a click event to those elements.

How can I follow the link correctly?

Previous code:

```
<a href="Page1.html">
   <button>Page 1</button>
</a>
```

New code:

```
<button onclick="document.location.href= 'Page1.html'">Page 1</button>
```

With the code above testing locally I go from:

`file://directory/to/home.html`

to

`file://Page1.html`

But the page is in the same directory at:

`file://directory/to/Page1.html`

In other words I have to proceed without being able to use an anchor tag but do my best to represent it.

Should I add a title with the page location to show the target location? Is there a way to simulate the location that shows in the footer when hovering over a link?

Answer (score 2):

Use a relative path instead:

```
<button onclick="document.location.href='./Page1.html'">Page 1</button>
```

Even better, attach the listener properly using Javascript, since inline handlers are generally considered to be pretty poor practice, and have scoping and escaping issues:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.href = './Page1.html';
});
```

You can use similar syntax to navigate up a level, without going all the way back to the root directory. Eg

```
window.location.href = '../Page1.html';
```

when running on

```
file://directory/to/home.html
```

will take you to

```
file://directory/home.html
```

Comment: OK put a `"./"` before the page. Do I use `window.location` or `document.location`?

Comment: Best to use [`window.location`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430936/). Both will work on modern browsers, but `window.location` is probably what most programmers expect to see, so it's a better choice

Answer (score 1):

- `./` Denotes your current directory's path
- `../` Denotes your previous directory's path
- `/` Denotes your root path

In above case you should add current Directory's path:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='./Page1.html'">Page 1</button>
```

> **./Page%201** => will take you to **file://directory/to/home.html**
>
> **../Page%201** => **file://directory/home.html**
>
> **/Page%201**   => **file://Page%201**