# Javascript - Redirect if the value in a input box is correct

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem, I'm doing a little game and I made a level, where you just have to change the level number to go to the next level, but when the correct value is sent it's supposed to redirect to the next level but it doesn't work ...

```js
function getVal() {
    var nmb = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var element = document.getElementById('input');
    element.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        if(nmb == 3) {
            document.location.href = "aw3za.html";  //If the value is correct it redirects to the level 3
        }
        else {
            document.location.href = "2ksdkwa.html"; //If the value isn't correct it stays on the level 2
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>RodrigueSS 2 | Level 2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/level_template.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/level2_style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/57d547920e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="assets/script/level2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/script/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <div class="prev-page-container">
            <a href="level1.html"><img class="prev-page-arrow" src="assets/img/prev-arrow.svg" alt="Back arrow"></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--This is the interesting part--------->
    <div class="level-number-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="level-number-container">
            <form method="GET" name="form1">
                <input onclick="getVal()" id="input" name="numbox1" class="level-number" type="number">
            </form>
        </div>                         
    </div>
    <!---------------------------------------> 
    <footer>
        <div class="media-container">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="media-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/r_dr_go/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="media-link"href="https://twitter.com/Rodrigu40035063"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably an issue with your path to the html file. What happens when you try to directly navigate to `aw3za.html`? Do you get a 404 response?

Comment: probably blocked by browser as popup

Comment: When I open the file, it opens correctly

Comment: If the browser detects it as a popup, how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

To the people that have this problem, Here is the JS, I put a window.onload, it means that it only launch when the page is completely loaded :

```js
window.onload = function() {

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if(document.getElementById('input').value == 3) {
             window.location.href = "aw3za.html"
     }
 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**document.location** has been deprecated for almost as long as JavaScript has existed. Don't use it So use **window.location**

```
function getVal() {
    var nmb = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var element = document.getElementById('input');
    element.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        if(nmb == 3) {
            window.location = "aw3za.html";  //If the value is correct it redirects to the level 3
        }
        else {
            window.location = "2ksdkwa.html"; //If the value isn't correct it stays on the level 2
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

Comment: `window.location = 'url.html' is better.

Comment: My HTML Page is in another folder i tried to make the relative path, like '../../aw3za.html' and still don't work

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need trigger `onClick` function on input box. that function only execute when you click on that. So when you clicking that value is empty. then when you try to perform `keyup` the value will be empty. Actually you can use `document.location.href`.
Problem is your arrangement. Try this

```js
var element = document.getElementById('input');
element.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  var nmb = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if(nmb == 3){
    console.log('in');
    document.location.href = "new.html";
  }
    
})
```

```html
<div class="level-number-wrapper">
  <div class="level-number-container">
    <form method="GET" name="form1">
       <input id="input" name="numbox1" class="level-number">
    </form>
 </div>                         
</div>
```

Comment: I have an error in the console, addEventListener of null

Comment: I don't have that. Did you see in here too ?

Comment: Yes it underlines element.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {

Comment: I tried it in Mozilla and he displays me an error too "element is null"

Comment: Where did you assign `element` ?

Comment: In my url bar after, it displays me ?numbox1=3, does that cause any problem ??

Comment: I assigned it in the first line of my script : var element = document.getElementById('input');

Answer (score 1):

Several things here:
First you have an extra div closing in the interesting part of your code here:

```
<div class="level-number-wrapper"></div>
```

you should erase it.

Second, you don't need to use the function getVal() to add an event listener, you should add it directly.

Last, if you are staying in the same page if unless you change the value to 3 then you don't need the else part of the if.
This being said, this code works for me, check it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>RodrigueSS 2 | Level 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/level_template.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/level2_style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/57d547920e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/script/level2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/script/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="prev-page-container">
        <a href="level1.html"><img class="prev-page-arrow" src="assets/img/prev-arrow.svg" alt="Back arrow"></a>
    </div>
</header>
<!--This is the interesting part--------->
<div class="level-number-wrapper">
    <div class="level-number-container">
        <form method="GET" name="form1">
            <input id="input" name="numbox1" class="level-number" type="number">
        </form>
    </div>                         
</div>
<!---------------------------------------> 
<footer>
    <div class="media-container">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="media-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/r_dr_go/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a class="media-link"href="https://twitter.com/Rodrigu40035063"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
<script>
   document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
   if(document.getElementById('input').value == 3) {
            document.location.href = "aw3za.html"
    }
})</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think you can use both location and window but window is a bit better for cross browser safety as stated here: 
[What's the difference between window.location and document.location in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip)

Comment: My HTML tag was closed

Comment: Ok, i fixed it, there was a problem with my js file, I put it in HTML and now it works, thx. I made the same thing in my js file and it doesn't work, I checked if the file was correctly linked and it is, kinda weird tho...

Comment: When I put it in my JS file console display me addEventListener of null

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem, it always do that to me, I put a window.onload = function() { on the first line and It works !!!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that, when something doesn't work I normally try to move js to html and more than once I realized that solved the problem

Comment: Honestly It's my first time asking a Question in Stack Overflow, and I love it !! I love how the community is ready to help, Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

> window.open

Calling ***window.open*** function in the listener had made the browser open the tab.

**Here is the working code:**

**1. index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="level-number-wrapper">
    <div class="level-number-container">
        <form method="GET" name="form1">
            <input id="input" name="numbox1" class="level-number" type="number">
        </form>
    </div>                         
</div>
<script>
   document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
   if(document.getElementById('input').value == 3) {
      window.open("aw3za.html")
    }
})</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. aw3za.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Level 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>AW3ZA</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
 document.location.href
```

By

```
 window.location
```

Comment: please what aw3za.html and 2ksdkwa.html represent?

Comment: aw3za is the level 3 and 2ksdkwa is the level 2

Comment: Try to do this: window.location='../../aw3za.html'

Comment: Can you check this path '../../aw3za.html'? Is it correct? When I click in the fields I am redirected