# How Can I go to another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, `document.location.href` ,  `window.location.href` ,  and  `window.location.replace` is not working, I'm using localhost for now and I don't know how to redirect it to another webpage. I tried adding http:// on front, it's still not working, I tried making it redirect to another online website, It also didn't work.  I read a lot of thread already and tried them but none of them worked for me.

```
var loginBut = document.getElementById("RDbtn1");
loginBut.addEventListener("click", checklogin);
function check(){
    document.location.href =  "http://localhost/some/directory/here";
    alert(document.location.origin + '/some/directory');  // I just use this to know that the button is being pressed.

}
```

html:

```
  <!-- some code here-->
<li><button class="login1" id="RDbtn1">LOGIN</button></li>
  <!-- some code here -->
```

Comment: i think is :
- name of function check & you called as checklogin in addeventlistener

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should redirect to particular html page and should give the port on which your local host application is working

```
document.location.href =  "http://localhost:8080/some/directory/here/file.html";
```

Comment: I tried adding it, and it  still didn't work, my port number is 80 and changed it but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is window.location (nothing or replace or href) - document.location is normally used to get the actual page

[What's the difference between window.location and document.location in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip)

2. If you are on the same server, no need to qualify the page but I would add the actual page you try to load

---

```
window.location = "/some/directory/here/index.html"
```

Comment: It does work but it doesn't redirect, instead it shows that it is being canceled on the networks tab. Here's the screenshot. https://snipboard.io/uegXRi.jpg

Comment: What is the file you want to load? I see `check` is that a directory? If so, is directory browsing turned on?

Comment: check is a php file. I add php on the end of the file at the code just to make sure.