# how to Call a jsp page using jquery via button click

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
 <input type="button" value="Refer Candidate" class="formbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recruiterModal">
```

I want to call a jsp page through a button click using jquery.

Comment: what call would you like to make?

Comment: i want to open a jsp page through button click. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use an anchor (a) and style it how you want? That's what they are designed for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a button redirect to another page using jQuery or just Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238368/how-to-make-a-button-redirect-to-another-page-using-jquery-or-just-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `form` tag which wraps the `input` tag with `type=submit` and in the `form`'s `action` attribute you can specify the JSP page's link.

```
<form action='jsp-page-to-call.jsp'>
  <input type="submit" value="Refer Candidate" class="formbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recruiterModal">
</form>
```

So on click of the Submit Button the request goes to the JSP Page.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS

```
    <form id="frmID">
      <input type="submit" value="Refer Candidate" class="formbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recruiterModal">
    </form>

   On button click
document.getElementById("frmID").action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/YourjspPage.jsp";
document.getElementById("frmID").submit();
```

Comment: thanks pawan for your help but i am not using any form tag as my button is in div tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="buttonid" type="button" value="Refer Candidate" class="formbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recruiterModal">

   $('#buttonid').click(function(){
      window.open('yourJspPageHere.jsp','_blank');
   });
```

is this what you're looking for?

Comment: where to place the above jquery code as my button is inside the <div>. The code is displaying in jsp page accordingly wherever i am pasting it.

Comment: do u have a separate js file? this is probably a bad practice but as i've no idea about your application structure, you can place the code after the </div> inside <script>.....</script> tags

Comment: thanks Pragun for all your help. it's working now but while clicking on button getting 404 error as requested resource not available. Any help??

Comment: thats because you've to specify the location of your jsp page.

Comment: where to specify the location as both the jsp pages are located in the same location.

Comment: window.open('./yourJspPageNameHere.jsp','_blank'); try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127343/discussion-between-rabindra-and-pragun).